# What information should be in the github README.md?

Tags: documentation, github

What information would you expect to see in the github README?

Should everything go in the README? i.e.

- Introduction
- Installation
- Versions
- User Guide
- Implementation
- Testing
- Related Resources

Or should you just put certain things in the README (Introduction, Installation, Versions) and the other information is best placed in the Github wiki?

Comment: I would put licence terms also

Comment: In overly general terms, there should be enough information to tell me whether the project is useful to me if all I know about it is the name. Don't assume anything about how the reader found it.

Comment: This question has a very detailed/good answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304863/how-to-write-a-good-readme

Comment: You can easily provide links to other markdown documents.

Comment: I think this is a matter of opinion and expectations. Some people put high-level architecture in README.md, troubleshooting, faq, some just the how-to-run section.

Answer (score 8):

I expect to see an introduction and brief overview. There should be something there to convince me that the project solves a particular problem. After reading the README, I should know enough information to  know what the project does, what it requires, how to build it, and how to use it. That information doesn't all need to be in the README, but links to that information should be.

Comment: +1 for brief.  Don't say "README" and then put a bunch of garbage in that doesn't need to be read.